# Email whenever someone posts to a vBulletin forum

Tags: email

I read an online forum that runs on [vBulletin](https://www.vbulletin.com/). I want to be alerted by email whenever a specific user makes a post onto the forum.

Is there any software or web application that can monitor the forum and send me an email whenever the user makes a post?

Comment: Does the forum have an RSS feed? If yes, then you could probably set up an app with a filter and notifications. I'm not sure if there are any that support email though.

Comment: @Timmy I found an old post from the admin of the forum saying that he eliminated his RSS, XML, and JScript feeds.

Comment: I doubt that leaves a chance to solve your question. Unless the forum itself provides subscription/notification options, I see no other way

Answer (score 1):

I've send a mail to the support team of vBulletin asking about the subscription procedure and here is what I got as an answer:

> Hello,
>
> To subscribe to a user on the vBulletin.com forums first find a post by the user. Click on their username below their avatar.
>
> On the next page you will see a "Subscribe" button, press it to subscribe.
>
> A screenshot of the button location is here:
>   https://tmpdmp.com/254cb5d954cf631d/13239f4f5202738e
>
> Please let me know if you require any further assistance with this issue.
>
> - Joe D.
>   vBulletin Support Staff

I hope this help your issue!

Comment: Do you have a backup of the screenshot? It is not accessible anymore.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'm afraid the link was provided from the support team of vBulletin and I didn't create any backup screenshot of it :-(. However, regarding this thread you can have a look [here](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-legacy-versions-products/legacy-vbulletin-versions/vbulletin-3-6-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/266365-subscribe-to-user)